# Using BeautifulSoup to pick up text in table, on webpages

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to use BeautifulSoup to pick up the ‘Model Type’ values on company’s webpages which from codes like below:

it forms 2 tables shown on the webpage, side by side.

**updated source code of the webpage**

```
<TR class=tableheader>
<TD width="12%">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: left" width="12%">Group </TD>
<TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: left" width="15%">Model Type </TD>
<TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: left" width="15%">Design Year </TD></TR>
<TR class=row1>
<TD width="10%">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD class=row1>South West</TD>
<TD>VIP QB662FG (Registered) </TD>
<TD>2013 (Registered) </TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD></TR>
```

I am using following however it doesn’t get the ‘VIP QB662FG’ wanted:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url = "http://www.thewebpage.com"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

find_it = soup.find_all(text=re.compile("Model Type "))
the_value = find_it[0].findNext('td').contents[0]

print the_value
```

in what way I can get it? I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: Is there more context? Is it always the 3rd column in the table, are there other rows that don't have Model Type columns?

Comment: dear Mr. Pieters, there are more texts on the page. there's only 1 'Model Type' on the page and always the same position.

Comment: What I am asking for is for you to show more context; there may be better ways to home in on that one row and cell.

Comment: Or just show us the webpage. Otherwise we can't know if, say `soup.css('.row1 td')[2].get_text()` would work.

Comment: @parchment: which is basically what I am getting at, yes.

Comment: dear both, as it's a company's internal. i can't show it all...i supplied more in the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the next *row*, then the next cell in the same position. The latter is tricky; we could assume it is always the 3rd column:

```
header_text = soup.find(text=re.compile("Model Type "))
value = header_cell.find_next('tr').select('td:nth-of-type(3)')[0].get_text()
```

If you just ask for the next `td`, you get the `Design Year` column instead.

There could well be better methods to get to your one cell; if we assume there is only one `tr` row with the class `row1`, for example, the following would get your value in one step:

```
value = soup.select('tr.row1 td:nth-of-type(3)')[0].get_text()
```

Comment: thanks Mr. Pieters. but it gives an error 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next'.

Comment: @MarkK: so your original search for `Model Type` is failing. BeautifulSoup is not finding that table cell.

Comment: It's working. Take the value for soup in my answer and try Martijn Pieters's solution, it's working ;)

Comment: @Mr. Pieters, I spelled the keyword wrongly. Yes, it isn't error message but not picking the wanted. Is it because there's another table beside the one gave? Please see my edited question. thanks.

Comment: @DavidK: With the edited source it still works for me. It'd be a lot more helpful if we could get the *whole* page.

Comment: @Mr. Pieters. Fainted!! I just run the code, without added 'print value' so there's no output. You are right, and correct. 100 scores!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do as follows :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<TD colSpan=3>Desinger </TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD class=row2bold width="5%">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD class=row2bold width="30%" align=left>Gender </TD>
<TD class=row1 width="20%" align=left>Male </TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD class=row2bold width="5%">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD class=row2bold width="30%" align=left>Born Country </TD>
<TD class=row1 width="20%" align=left>DE </TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD>
<TD height="100%" vAlign=top>
<TABLE class=tableforms>
<TBODY>
<TR class=tableheader>
<TD colSpan=4>Remarks </TD></TR>

<TR class=tableheader>
<TD width="12%">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: left" width="12%">Group </TD>
<TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: left" width="15%">Model Type </TD>
<TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: left" width="15%">Design Year </TD></TR>
<TR class=row1>
<TD width="10%">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD class=row1>South West</TD>
<TD>VIP QB662FG (Registered) </TD>
<TD>2013 (Registered) </TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD></TR>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
soup = soup.find('table',{'class':'tableforms'})

dico = {}
l1 = soup.findAll('tr')[1].findAll('td')
l2 = soup.findAll('tr')[2].findAll('td')
for i in range(len(l1)):
    dico[l1[i].getText().strip()] = l2[i].getText().replace('(Registered)','').strip()

print dico['Model Type']
```

It prints : `u'VIP QB662FG'`

Comment: thanks DavidK, it works but not in the updated codes. could you please have a look? thanks.

Comment: thanks DavidK. it works on the given codes but when i put it on using the real page, it gives wrror "list index out of range". blaming me can't provide the full page...

Comment: It depends on the webpage. By soup.findAll('tr')[1], I skip soup.findAll('tr')[0] because it's empty : <TR class=tableheader>
<TD colSpan=4>Remarks </TD></TR>

Answer (score 1):

Find all tr's and output it's third child unless it's first row

```
import bs4    
data = """
<TR class=tableheader>
<TD width="12%">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: left" width="12%">Group </TD>
<TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: left" width="15%">Model Type </TD>
<TD style="TEXT-ALIGN: left" width="15%">Design Year </TD></TR>
<TR class=row1>
<TD width="10%">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD class=row1>South West</TD>
<TD>VIP QB662FG (Registered) </TD>
<TD>2013 (Registered) </TD>
"""
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data)
#table = soup.find('tr', {'class':'tableheader'}).parent
table = soup.find('table', {'class':'tableforms'})
for i,tr in  enumerate(table.findChildren()):
    if i>0:
        for idx,td in enumerate(tr.findChildren()):
            if idx==2:
                print td.get_text().replace('(Registered)','').strip()
```

Comment: thanks, xecgr. your code is Magnificent. But it gets more texts than the wanted, as there are other texts on the page fits it.

Comment: what about now? iterate all tr of tableheader tr's parent (main table)?

Comment: i've used the selector that now will work with html-snippet (table class 'tableforms')